# Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake: reading initial communication packet', system error: 10060

Tags: mysql, vba, servidor, mariadb, odbc

Olá,

Construí um aplicativo simples em VBA para minha empresa e estava funcionando perfeitamente em Access, porém preciso migrar para MySQL por conta de limitações do Access.

Consegui realizar a transferência do banco para o MySQL porém somente em localhost.

Assinei um serviço de servidor para testar e agora não consigo conectar com ele, recebendo sempre a mensagem de erro do título, alguem já teve esse problema ou tem alguma ideia do que possa ser?

O código está assim: (está funcionando perfeitamente no localhost)

```
Public BD As New ADODB.Connection

Sub conectarBD()
Set BD = New ADODB.Connection

BD.ConnectionString = "DRIVER= {MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};" _
                            & "SERVER='IP'; Port=XXXX;" _
                            & "DATABASE='BD';" _
                            & "UID='USER';" _
                            & "PASSWORD='SENHA';"
                            
BD.Open CS
End Sub
```

OBS: Já tentei liberar a porta pelo Firewall e também mudar o bind-adress no terminal do servidor, porém não tive sucesso.

OBS2: No terminal do servidor eu não consigo editar o arquivo my.cnf, mas não existe a linha do bind-adress.
O código está assim no terminal: (embaixo da tela do terminal dá um aviso de que o my.cnf não pode ser editado)

```
[mysqld]
    default-storage-engine=MYISAM
    local-infile=0
    innodb_file_per_table=1
    max_connections=500
    max_user_connections=100
    open_files_limit = 10000
    local-infile = 0
    max_allowed_packet = 512M
    query_cache_type = 0
    query_cache_size = 0
    join_buffer_size = 1M
    tmp_table_size = 32M
    max_heap_table_size = 32M
    innodb_log_file_size= 100M
    sql_mode=""
```

OBS3: Nas configurações do banco de dados está definido acesso para qualquer ip "%".

Estou usando o InterServer como servidor, que usa o DirectAdmin como painel de controle. Qualquer ajuda será muito bem vindo, agradeço desde já!

Comment: Dê uma olhada se a porta que você está usando, mais detalhes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755819/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communication-packet-syste

Comment: Bom dia Vinicius! Então, eu tentei várias portas diferentes, e consegui descobrir que o padrão do servidor que estou usando é a porta 2222, que é a única porta que dá esse erro. As outras portas da um erro diferente, dizendo que não foi possível conectar com o banco. O erro é o seguinte: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP' (10060)

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Boa tarde, César! Resolvi utilizando um servidor na rede local apenas. Mas da maneira como eu queria online ainda não.